# Get user meta data after newly registration user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this function to get the information of User.But unfortunately i can't able to access the user meta data.Forexample first_name,last_name etc

```
function registerUserInSalesForce($user_ID)
{        
$firstname=get_user_meta($user_ID,'first_name',true);
update_option('update_meta',$firstname);

}
add_action( 'user_register', 'registerUserInSalesForce');
```

I am receiving newly register user's id from $user_ID but cannot able to get the value in $firstname.How can i get the user meta record after registering new user?
Thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 1):

[From codex results example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta#Getting_all_meta_data):

```
Array ( [first_name] => Array ( [0] => Tom ) [last_name] => Array ( [0] => Auger) [nickname] => Array ( [0] => tomauger ) [description] => etc.... )
```

That means, `first_name` is an array and you should access first element in array `first_name` to get it:

```
function registerUserInSalesForce($user_ID)
{        
$firstname=get_user_meta($user_ID,'first_name',true);
update_option('update_meta',$firstname[0]);
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'registerUserInSalesForce');
```

Comment: Thanks @ksno for replying.But actually in my case this is not an answer.

Comment: What do you mean is not an answer? You question, if we rephrase it, would be: **How to retrieve user meta data right after user registration?** And as post explains details, in this particular case, you aren't able to get `first_name` from new user. I just said exactly what to do and explained why it doesn't work. Check edit.

Comment: Sorry you didn't understand my comment.I was saying that your answer is not in my case because in my case first_name is not storing in database in any array form.Only string is going to save in database against first_name field.So thats why i can't take this answer right in my case.Thanks

Comment: You should edit your question **definitely**, so that somebody can answer it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be able to help, as it depends on which data do you need. But `firstName` and `lastName` are definitely available.

You need to use the `$userdata` parameter, and for that you need to provide and add some parameters to your functions:

```
function registerUserInSalesForce( $user_id, $userdata )
{        
    $firstname = $userdata['first_name'];
    //$firstname = $userdata['last_name'];
    update_option('update_meta', $firstname);
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'registerUserInSalesForce', 10, 2);
```

This information is part of the user's information, and it's not user meta. User meta doesn't exist yet when this hook triggers.